# How to implement multinode architecture in crossbar.io?

Tags: websocket, autobahn, autobahnws

I'm developing a decentralized(server and client) application architecture and use websockets as communication method between all servers and all clients.Multiple master servers federation.I am using crossbar on the server end and autobahn on the client. 
On the documentation page in [crossbar.io site](http://crossbar.io/docs/Architecture/) it says:

```
A Crossbar.io node is a single instance of the Crossbar.io software 
running on a single machine. This Crossbar.io node can form a cluster 
or federated network by connecting to other Crossbar.io nodes on the 
same, or, more often on other machines.Externally, the cluster will
behave like a single instance.
While application components connect to specific nodes or are directly 
hosted by specific nodes, this is transparent from an application 
point of view: application components are agnostic to how and where 
they are deployed.
```

[image: http://crossbar.io/docs/Architecture/]
Searching for direction on how to implement this architecture gave me no results either on the documentation pages or the web.
How is this architecture implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this part of the architecture is something we're still working on. Currently, there is no way to cluster Crossbar.io nodes.

It is unfortunate that the architecture page currently suggests that this is already available. I've added a note at the beginning of the page which clarifies that parts of the architecture are not implemented yet (will deploy the changed version today).

Sorry for misleading you there!

Comment: Is the clustering support there now?